# Access property from component in provider in angular2

Tags: oop, angular, typescript, ionic2

So I'm new to OOP and trying out ionic 2 with angular 2 with typescript.
Say I have an input in the home.html file that is coupled to username in home.ts like this:

```
export class HomePage {
public username: string;
public newusername: string; 
...
constructor(public users: UserService) {
...
```

Now I want a service (userService.ts) to take username from the input or home.ts and modify it and store the result as newusername.

Do I have to make a constructor in the service/provider like in Homepage which instantiates a new object of home though I already made an object of this in home.ts?

I imported HomePage in userServices but I cant access newusername because I didnt make an object of it.

Comment: how you want userService to read username? as you type or after typing the username when you press any button?

Comment: Its more a conceptual question so a button would do it.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to access to the component properties _directly_ from the service? It does not seems to be a good design though. A better approach would be `Component ---(call a method)--> Service ---(send result)---> Component`

Comment: Ok, that actually anwers my question. There isn't a reason I have to do this, I just wondered if there is a good way to do it but there apparently isn't :)

Comment: Oh I see... Glad I could help then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want but take a look at this if its good for you. (I'd use **newusername** in service itself)

**NOTE**: its has nothing to do with **Ionic2** as I don't know **Ionic2**.

**Working demo**: https://plnkr.co/edit/03oXUTZYwRRo8PTfDFlA?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {service} from './service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  New User : {{s.newusername}}<br>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username">
  <button (click)="click(username)">Add User</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 

  constructor(private s:service){
  }

  click(username){
    this.s.addUserName(username);
    console.log(this.s.newusername)
  }

}
```

**service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class service{

  newusername:string;
  addUserName(str){
    this.newusername=str;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call a service from code in the component, or pass the component to the service.

```
constructor(public users: UserService) {}

@Input() public username: string;
// called when an input was updated
ngOnChanges() {
  this.newusername = this.users.convertUserName(this.username);
}
```

or

```
constructor(public users: UserService) {
  users.component = this;
}
```

but this would still need some way to notify the service about changes to the input like in the above example.

Comment: I've done something similar to your first solution but I wonder if there is a direct way to access the newusername property from home.ts directly in my UserService so I can just call a method from the html from a button to set newusername to "xy".